# Таблица растягивается по высоте, хотя должна работать через скрол по ширине, в родительском диве overflow-x:auto

Tags: html, css

```css
.grape__table {
  margin: 30px 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table__vine {
  border: 2px solid #E6E3C4;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grape__table">
  <table class="table__vine">
    <tr>
      <td class="table__year">1980</td>
      <td class="table__title">Colli Euganei Bianco Ca' Lustra </br><span class="table__text"> Красочная бутылка вина из Марселя</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table__year">1980</td>
      <td class="table__title">Colli Euganei Bianco Ca' Lustra </br> <span class="table__text"> Красочная бутылка вина из Марселя</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table__year">1980</td>
      <td class="table__title">Colli Euganei Bianco Ca' Lustra </br> <span class="table__text"> Красочная бутылка вина из Марселя</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно я не прав. По моему мнению вы хотите создать горизонтальную табличку?

Comment: да, я добавил, как это выглядит разрешение 1920

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, вы пишите, что таблица растягивается по высоте. Хотя должна по ширине. Но вы же добавляете tr это строка, растягивает вниз. Добавьте td с определённой шириной. Или ограничте сам div

Comment: да, по моей задумке, она вообще растягиваться не должна. При адаптиве она должна равномерно уменьшаться, и работать через скрол по ширине. Я мало знаком с таблицами, поэтому руководствовался вот этим сайтом https://html5css.ru/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.php

Comment: Сейчас содержимое явно умещается, можно ограничеть div по ширине, и появится горизонтальный скрол

Comment: если вы о родительском диве, то если я ограничу ширину, адаптивность будет страдать, правый блок, будет сжиматься неравномерно, из-за того что левый будет иметь фиксированную ширину, а скрола, не будет, я уже пробовал ранее. Будет то что на первом изображение.